# How do I do end to end testing of a Springboot API?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking, junit5, mockmvc

I have the following test class to test my API, and I have the following code structure:

`package controller -> UserController.java`
`package service -> UserService.java`
`package repository -> UserRepository.java`

`package endtoend -> EndToEndTest.java`

```
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
class EndToEndTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Test
void shouldReturn200() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(get("/users/{username}", "testUser"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

***UserController.java*** has a Get mapping -> `@GetMapping("/users/{username}")`

But the test is returning an error that the application failed to start and it's missing bean of type UserService.

I feel that I am missing some mocks, as my controller calls service and service calls repository.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  `@SpringBootTest` annotation instead to fully load all beans in your app. This does not happen with `@WebMvcTest`

Comment: Thank you. I've tried adding SpringBootTest and
AutoConfigureMockMvc annotations, now I am getting a 404. But I know I have the endpoints; anything else I can try?

Comment: I was missing a slash ("/"). Works now, thank you :)